# Segfault reading/altering a global variable

Tags: c, global-variables

I've started to get comfortable with getopt() and how to use it. Right now I'm making a cat clone, camt, to teach myself some things, between them setting flags in execution.

My solution was to set global variable in my camt.h and to change them based on the flags I want to set. It looks something like this:

The code in camt.c is:

```
bool line_numbers = false;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int opt = 0;
    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv,  "n")) != -1){
        switch(opt){
            case 'n':
                line_numbers = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    int ch;
    FILE* foofile;
    int o_files = 1;
    do{
       //read file
       foofile = fopen(argv[o_files], "r");
       if(line_numbers){
          display_ln(foofile); //line-numbers
       }else{
           display(foofile); /"normal" cat
       }
       fclose(foofile);
       o_files++;
    }while(o_files < argc);
    printf("\n"); //final scape character for nice prompt
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Btw, I'd be surprised if there wasn't a better, *less utterly horrendous* method to set flags in a program, in which case I'd be grateful if you told it to me :)
Please take into consideration that I'm a beginner that can barely clone a repository with git, so please be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you declare it `extern`?

Comment: You declare `bar` as a boolean value, but call it like a function. You code should not even compile. Please provide a full, minimal example.

Comment: If `line_numbers` is extern, you need to have the actual values stored somewhere. The linker will need to understand where the value is stored.

Comment: @Cheatah, yes, I have my camt.h and my camt.c, `extern bool bar` is a global variable in camt.h that is set to true when the `-n` option is read.

Comment: @Cheatah, I just added some clarifications to the post. for it to be clearer, hope it works.

Comment: The request was for a [mcve] - not snippets.

Comment: @NateEldredge, oh, you learn something new everyday.

Comment: What is it that you find horrendous about the flag-setting?  Use of global variables? The `switch` statement? `getopt()`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I see it as too brute of a method (not like I can come up with a better one though). I came up with the global variable solution in the morning and tried it, as you could deduce, it doen't work.  I've started to poke around with some more correct programs like BSD/GNU/suckless utilities, but they are either too complex for me or use methods I cannot identify. I'd really like to make a ""professional"" program, no matter the simplicity. I want to make things the way it is normally irl, and actually using arguments is something that I want to teach myself.

Comment: @IñakiUlibarri, then I take your concern to be about the nature and location of the flag storage.  For small programs, it's not unusual to use global variables.  I don't have a problem with that for programs (as opposed to libraries), provided that the variables in question are treated as write-once: after their values are set or defaulted during program startup, they should be off-limits for further modification.

Comment: Depending on the option in question, it may be possible and appropriate to make some other kind of globally-visible change, instead.  For example, to redirect the standard output stream or adjust its buffering mode.  Where you want to avoid using global state at all, you need to record the flag information in some more localized form and pass it around to all the functions that need it.  Perhaps you would define a structure containing it, and pass around a pointer to that structure, for example.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I like the structure idea, so I implemented it, I still get the segfault though.... I discovered that the segfault happens in is the functions that print the file with line-numbers and not the global variable reading; I've been in a wild goose chase all along.... The problem is that the faulty function works on isolation, but not in integration. Idk what to do here to be honest.

Comment: @IñakiUlibarri, this is where you would engage a debugger such as GDB, or a memory-usage analyzer such as Valgrind.  Or both.  They can help you pinpoint where the program is wrong and what is wrong about it.  Chances are good that it comes down to dereferencing an invalid pointer value, but appropriate tools can help you determine the specifics.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I'll see a couple of gdb tutorials then. I may even make a new post in here if I can't fix it on my own :v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesus, that was a dumb fix. I wasn't having issues reading my global variable, but opening *the file*.

The problem was that I defaulted the `o_files`, which is what I use to know what file I'm reading, to 1. This wasn't a problem when the first argument was a file or I set a flag which ended the program immediatly, but it was when I gave an option and *ran the entire program*.

I was always defaulting the first argument as if it were a file; the program activated the `p_flags.line_numbers` flag correctly and then tried to read `-n`, argument 1, as if it were a file, which obviously didn't exist.

TL;DR: Pretty much, I was reading all my arguments as files and then tried to open them, this isn't a problem when all arguments are files, but it is when not **all** of them are.